# Is this example of a composition relationship correct?

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class House
{
        private Person owner;
        private List<Room> rooms;

        public House(Person _owner)
        {
            this.owner = _owner;
            this.rooms = new List<Room>();
        }

        public void AddRoom(Room r)
        {
            rooms.Add(r);
        }
}
```

I have this class, am I correct in saying there's a composition relationship between the House Class and the Room Class since if you destroy an instance of house the list of rooms is deleted with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of composition.   You're making one class using other classes.

However, your question is veers into garbage collection.

Will the contents of the Rooms property be deleted when the instance of House is destroyed?   Yes.  Eventually.  When the garbage collector gets around to it.   It may not disappear at the exact instant you think it does.

You can have greater control over the lifetime of things on the heap with deterministic finalization (mostly implemented through the **using** block, but you can also create explicit dispose methods).

Sorry for the long explanation here, but felt like you were asking two questions so decided to answer both - and didn't want a link-only answer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-net-components/0596102070/ch04s05.html

Comment: "Will the contents of the Rooms property be deleted when the instance of House is destroyed? Yes." => this is not always true, especially when dealing with events.

Comment: I have edited the question, is it still Composition if I instantiate the Room somewhere else and then just add it to the list within the class?

Comment: @NicolasVoron `rooms` is `private`, so when an instance is of `House` is garbage collected, the `rooms` field will become eligible for GC. That's unless the OP has omitted some code that publicly exposes the list instance, and some external code still hold's reference to it.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I misunderstood your meaning of "content of the rooms property" : you meant the `List` itself, i meant the content of that `List`. Nvm

Comment: @NicolasVoron Yes that makes sense; there could still be other references to individual `Room` instances when a `House` becomes eligible for garbage collection, meaning they would not be eligible. The `List` instance would though.

Comment: Correct, @JohnathanBarclay.   As soon as something is no longer referenced by anything, it is eligible for garbage collection.   Eligible being the key word.

Comment: I think that @NicolasVoron is making the point that some rooms may _never_ be garbage collected, if other references are persisted.

Answer (score 1):

While this is an example of composition, I find many examples of both composition and inheritance to be rather artificial.

Since the house is the only object to reference the room list, when the house is eligible for collection, the room list would also be so. The same might not be true for the owner, or the rooms, since the owner or rooms might have been added to other houses. Note that in c# and .Net we usually do not use the term "destroy", since the Garbage collector is responsible reclaiming memory, and we use the disposable/finalizer patterns to ensure other kinds of resources are reclaimed.

My preferred example of composition/inheritance would be geometry. A Square *has* four corners. A square *is a* rectangle (at least if it is immutable). This has direct application in many programs, so actually provides a useful abstraction.

I would recommend reading [Eric Lipperts Wizards and Warriors](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) for more about object orientation.